# running a mysqli update query in php and it returns that it updated when it doesnt

Tags: php, mysqli

So what is happening is when I submit the page it should register that a user has already submitted a hope and then update that to their new one they just submitted instead of creating a new one, however when runs, it returns that it has successfully updated when it has not, any ideas on what to change to make it run correctly?

I have checked that it is grabbing all the information that is needed to run the update query by echoing out both the hope and the hopeId retrieved from the server and they come out correctly. Then I ran the update query directly in mysql workbench with the returned hope and hopeId and it successfully updates the row. From this I believe that have made a mistake while writing the statement in the MySQLDAO.

This is my code, its over a few pages so I grabbed all the code that I believed was relevant and labeled them separately(if you need any other code just shout and ill add it as an edit as soon as I can):

This is the todaysHope.php

```
$dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
$dao->openConnection();

$userHope = $dao->getHope($userId);

if(!empty($userHope))
{
    $hopeId=$userHope["hopeId"];

    $updateResult =$dao->updateTodaysHope($hopeId, $hope);

    if ($updateResult)
    {
        $returnValue["status"]="200";
        $returnValue["message"]="Hope updated";
        $returnValue["hope"]=$hope;
    } else {
        $returnValue["status"]="400";
        $returnValue["message"]="A problem has occured";
    }

} else  {

    $result =$dao->saveTodaysHope($userId, $hope);

    if ($result)
    {
        $returnValue["status"]="200";
        $returnValue["message"]="Hope submitted";  
    } else {
        $returnValue["status"]="400";
        $returnValue["message"]="A problem has occured";
    }

}
```

This is the MySQLDAO.php

```
public function saveTodaysHope($userId, $hope) 
    {
        $sql = "insert into todaysHope set userId=?, hope=?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if (!statement)
            throw new Exception ($statement->error);

        $statement->bind_param("is", $userId, $hope);
        $returnValue = $statement->execute();

        return $returnValue;

}

public function updateTodaysHope($hope, $hopeId) 
    {
        $sql = "update todaysHope set hope=? where hopeId=?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if (!statement)
            throw new Exception ($statement->error);

        $statement->bind_param("si", $hope, $hopeId);
        $returnValue = $statement->execute();

        return $returnValue;

}
```

Sorry if this is something really straight forward that I am just missing but I have been trying to get this bit of code to work for a couple days now and cant think of anything else to try. Thank you for helping.

Comment: It is a bit unclear are you creating a new one or just not updating?

Comment: @nerdlyist It looks like he's creating a new one if there isn't one, otherwise updating it. He could do it all in one query by using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're passing your variables the wrong way round to the function:

```
$updateResult =$dao->updateTodaysHope($hopeId, $hope);

public function updateTodaysHope($hope, $hopeId)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `$` in your $statement variable. Change this `if (!statement)` to `if (!$statement)` in both tests.

Answer (score 0):

If MySQLDAO is a subclass of PDO then $statement->execute() will return a boolean value.
The number of affected rows can be retrieved with $statement->rowCount().

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

---

For mysqli it is quite the same, execute() returns just boolean value, but there then it is not a method but a property to get the affected rows - would be `$statement->affected_rows`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: The question is tagged `mysqli`, so he's probably using mysqli, not PDO.

Comment: Either way, I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. He's already using the result as a boolean value in his `if()` statements.

Comment: Your update query will be succesful, even when no rows are updated (setting the same value again).

But i guess that was not his problem.